# Share variables between golang templates

Tags: go, go-templates

I want to generate 2 separate files with GOtemplate, let's say I have this code :

```
aBuffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
bBuffer := new(bytes.Buffer)

aTmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles(aFilePath)
aTmpl.Execute(aBuffer, someVariables)

bTmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles(bFilePath)
bTmpl.Execute(bBuffer, someVariables)
```

Let's say I use a common var for these two files (not coming from the "someVariables" golang var), do I have a way to declare it in a seperate file like with Helm ?

```
{{ define myVar }}
the-var
{{ end }}
```

Then to keep a kind of context that I can re-use in both aTmpl & bTmpl :

```
{{ template myVar .}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a third file with the common definitions:

```
{{define "myVar"}}
the-var
{{end}}
```

Parse that file with the others:

```
aTmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles(aFilePath, commonFilePath)

bTmpl, _ := template.ParseFiles(bFilePath, commonFilePath)
```

Use "myvar" in the two templates as follows:

```
{{template "myVar" .}}
```

Comment: I feel so dumb, should have thought about it.. Thanks !